# How to download a file on clicking thefile path using PHP-Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, upload, symfony-1.4

I'm creating a website using symfony for blogging. Users can upload their posts to the site. when a user add a file it will save inside `web/upload/file_upload` and the file path will save in `add_post` table. When a admin view a `add_post` table template he can see the path of the downloaded file of each and every user, what i want to do is through this file path download the file.

How can i do this?

**edit 1:**

Model - Blog_user Module - post

Table Structre - table name- Blog_user

```
 1  user_id      bigint(20)      
 2 gender       varchar(255)             
 3  blog_status  tinyint(1)      
 4 file         varchar(255)
```

Form

```
'user_id' => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(), 
'gender'  => new sfWidgetFormInputText(), 
'file'    => new sfWidgetFormInputFile(),
```

Here when uploading a file, the filepath save in Blog_user table and file save inside web/upload directory.

**edit 2:**

//save file method

```
public function saveFile(){
    $file = $this->getValue('file');
    if(isset($file)){
        $filename = 'POST_Uploaded -' .($file->getOriginalName());
        $file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/post_upload'.'/'.$filename);
    }
}
```

`E:\xampp\htdocs\trunk\web\uploads\post_upload\POSt_Uploaded -JS.pdf`

This how it saved in side web/upload/post_upload directory and same path will save inside db also

**edit 3:**

when a user upload a blog it will save in blog_user table and it consist blog _id as primary key, user_id is on user table. what i want do is when user upload a file , both user_id , and blog_id should be saved inside blog table . how to do it?

user table -  user_id , file(uploaded file)

blog table -  blog_id - there are blog titles , each title has an unique blog id , so that     user can upload a file under each titles,

post table - post_id, blog_id, user_id

Comment: Are you using the admin generator for the admin view? And btw, symfony 1.4 or 2.0?

Comment: no im not using admin generator.. im using symfony 1.4.16

Comment: You don't have an id for the table? What is the primary key of the blog_user table?

Comment: Could you show us and exemple of `file` from your db?

Comment: E:\xampp\htdocs\trunk\web\uploads/post_upload/post_Uploaded -JS.pdf                               this is how it save inside db

Comment: Can't you save only the filename, like `post_Uploaded -JS.pdf` ? It will be easier to retrieve them, and it's not a god idea to store the absolute path to the file since it depends on the machine (here you local machine).

Comment: yes, i also want to save it like that but  i dont know how to do it .. i've mention the save method above edited space.can  you please go through it and let me know if there any mistakes the way i have used there?

Comment: File Save

 public function saveFile(){
        $file = $this->getValue('file');
        if(isset($file)){
            $filename = 'post_Uploaded -' .($file->getOriginalName());
            $file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/post_upload'.'/'.$filename);
        }

Comment: Put it in your question instead..

Comment: ok done.. sorry im not very familiar with stackOverflow.. thats why im always doing it wrongly when putting commnets

Comment: Do not remove all your post when editing, add the fresh information at the bottom.

Comment: But, humm, this is not the way you save the filename in db. The `saveFile` you show save the file in the filesystem, not in db.

Comment: ok , next time i'll do like that.

Comment: i didnt get that @jok. i have wrote that saveFile method inside my form ..

Comment: you  mean do i have use two methods to save in db and filesystem seperatly.

Comment: update your post with the Form class of Blog_user

Comment: that mean inside addBlogForm.php right? so what do i need to update.. SaveFile method?

Comment: Sorry, when I say update your post, I mean your question :)

Comment: @j0k hey its working now.. thankyou.. now i can d/l the file :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming:

- your module name is `moduleName`
- the model with the file is `BlogUser`
- the primary key of the model is `id`

I will go this way:

In your template:

```
<a href="<?php echo url_for('post/download?user_id='.$blog_user->getUserId()) ?>">Download file</a>
```

Then, in your action (use the function from *Miqdad Ali*):

```
  public function executeDownload(sfwebRequest $request)
  {
    $blog_user = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Blog_user')->find($request->getParameter('user_id'));
    $this->forward404Unless($blog_user);

    header('content-type:');
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($blog_user->getFile()));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($blog_user->getFile()));
    ob_clean();
    flush();

    readfile($blog_user->getFile());

    return sfView::NONE;
  }
```

Comment: it give me a error 404                                                                                 The requested URL /frontend_dev.php/application/download/user_id//home/MyBlog/trunk/web/uploads/post_upload/post.pdf was not found on this server

Comment: Well, give me more information. Update your question with: the model name, the module name, the table structure and one content. And I will update my answer.

Comment: Model - Blog_user = Application
Module - post                                                                         
--------------------
Table Structre - table name- Blog_user

user_id bigint(20)  gender varchar(255)   
 blog_status tinyint(1)  
  file varchar(255)

Comment: @farah better edit your answer and put these informations inside, it will be more easy to read it.

Comment: Form - 
    'user_id'            => new sfWidgetFormInputHidden(),
    'gender'             => new sfWidgetFormInputText(),
    'file'                 =>  new sfWidgetFormInputFile(),

Comment: can u please tell how to structre the comment..why it always display as paragraph?

Comment: If you want to provide more information, like code, structure, etc .. [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10894166/edit). You can't format the comment using paragraph.

Comment: There is one more thing that i have to clarify with you @j0k                     when a user upload a blog it will save in blog_user table and it consist blog _id as primary key, user_id is on user table. what i want do is when user upload a file , both user_id , and blog_id should be saved inside blog table . how to do it?

Comment: Well you will need to retrieve the `blog_id` and put it in a hidden field. But I don't know how to do (a bit complex without the code, the project, etc ..)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this file inside any controller and call that function while user clicking on the download

```
function download(){
    $file = "path/to/the/file.zip";
    if (file_exists($file)) {
      exit;
    }
   header('content-type:');
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   //header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
   ob_clean();
   flush();
   readfile($file);
   exit;
}
```

Comment: ok, on my listAllPost template there i display all the posts the i passed the paramete of each user_id  and using addPost template im displaying all the details regarding to the user such as User ID, User Type, Post Title and Post. There under the post it displays the file path of that particular file which user upload. so is it posible to me to give a that path as a link and download that file?

Comment: You can call like this yourdomain.com/controller/download/filename and change the function to function download($argument)

Comment: here what i did so far --                                                                                        i create a link to path of the file , like this 
<a href="<?php echo url_for(''.$blog_user->getPost()) ?>"><?php echo $blog_user->getPost() ?></a></p> 

and it output - 
/home/dev/myBlog/trunk/web/uploads/post_upload/post_title.pdf

this is my controller
 Public function execute($request)
    {
      $this->jobseeker = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Jobseeker')->find(array($request->getParameter('user_id')));

    } is it ok to use the method which u have metion earlier according to this?

Comment: for example I am writing this function in controller files  then I am calling this like <a href="files/download/post_title.pdf">Download</a>  and i will change file path and name in download method